# Get a unique list/tuple element given a condition in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, conditional-statements

How do I get a tuple/list element given a condition in python?
This occurs pretty often and I am looking for a nice-few-lines-pythonic way of doing this.

here could be an example:

Consider a tuple containing 2D points coordinates like this:

```
points = [[x1, y1],[x2, y2],[x3, y3], ...]
```

And I would like to get **the** point that minimizes the euclidean distance given an arbitrary point (say [X, Y] for instance, my point is : it is not contained in the list!)

```
def dist(p1, p2):
    return sqrt((p2[0]-p1[0])**2+(p2[1]-p1[1])**2)
pointToCompare2 = [X, Y]
```

Anyone having a freaky one liner(or not) for that?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're only checking whether a point is closer instead of returning the distance note that it's a good idea to remove the square root from the distance calculation making the calculation much faster. ;) You could have a seperate function, I usually call it 'distPow', for getting the closest point. If you then want the distance you can use your dist function on only that point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
min(points, key=lambda x: dist(pointToCompare2, x))
```

[min is a built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min).

Answer (score 0):

```
v = [1,3,2,4,7,3,3,4,5,11]

def get_num_uniques(v):
    count = []
    dup = []
tmp = []
for i in v:
    if i not in count:
        count.append(i)
    else:
        dup.append(i)
        count.remove(i)
for j in count:
    if j not in dup:
        tmp.append(j)

return tmp

#Call the function
print get_num_uniques(v)
```